# Max Timestamp not giving correct result

Tags: oracle, plsql, timestamp, max

I have a simple code to display latest error msg based on timestamp:

```
SELECT 
            line_item || ': ' || error_msg as RejectionMsg
            FROM reqs
            WHERE reqs_number = 'XXXXXXX' 
            and  rqj_timestamp = (select max(rqj_timestamp) from reqs
            WHERE reqs_number  = 'XXXXXX' )
```

My data is something like :

```
rqj_timestamp         line_item Error_msg 
08-MAY-2009 14:00:04    8928    INVALID (RC4C) E
08-MAY-2009 14:00:04    8929    INVALID (R4CO) EY0
05-AUG-2013 00:13:42    11760   OO_USR_1 - NO_DATA_FOUND:No Data found for REQUEST
05-AUG-2013 00:13:42    11761   OO_USR_1 - NO_DATA_FOUND:No Data found for REQUEST
05-AUG-2013 00:13:42    11762   OO_USR_1 - NO_DATA_FOUND:No Data found for REQUEST
05-AUG-2013 00:14:59    11763   OO_USR_1 - NO_DATA_FOUND:No Data found for REQUEST
06-AUG-2013 06:55:59    11807   OO_45_ERROR_REGION_DERIV
06-AUG-2013 06:55:59    11808   OO_45_ERROR_REGION_DERIV
06-AUG-2013 06:55:59    11809   OO_45_ERROR_REGION_DERIV
```

My query is giving me output for 08-MAY-2009 14:00:04 time-stamp instead of the 06-AUG-2013 06:55:59 time-stamp.

```
3: INVALID (RC4C) E                                                         
3: INVALID (R4CO) EY0
```

Any idea where I am going wrong in this?OR how i can improve my query.. if i remove    08-MAY-2009 14:00:04 rows, it works perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would assuem your timestamp is not a date or similar data type, but a character data type like nvarchar2. Change you table to the proper data type.

A working but less clean solution would be to use something like

```
cast((select max(cast(rqj_timestamp as date)) from reqs) as nvarchar2)
```

which might depend on national language settings etc.
You would use the character data type that the column has in the outer `cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (untested):

```
select *
from (
  select r.*, 
  row_number() over (partition by reqs_number order by rqj_timestamp desc nulls last) rnum
  from reqs r
  where reqs_number = 'XXXXXXX'
)
where rnum = 1;
```

Also, the assumption is the "rqj_timestamp" is actually a timestamp (or at least a date).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out to check the datatype..turns out it was varchar, adding `to_date(rqj_timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`  worked.